# c# how to get specific string

Tags: c#, asp.net, substring, string-parsing

Hi I am facing problem to get specific string. The string as below:

```
string myPurseBalance = "Purse Balance: +0000004000 556080";
```

I want to get 4000 out only.

Comment: What is your pattern? You want to get last `4` digits that starts with `+` for example?

Comment: If you want to extract desired value from the passed string and you know the format you want to output. You can use Regular Expression to do so

Comment: Use SubString. myPursebalance.SubString(22,4);

Comment: @captainsac I don't think this is a good way. It works on this case but it is not a general solution..

Comment: @SonerGönül As there is only one string specified and is there is no any pattern then substring is a good way to go for

Comment: @SonerGönül - Given the amount of effort provided by the OP I think its a pretty good answer. OP, what have you tried?

Comment: I like when one comes here, ask (politely) as simple enough question that he/she should at least try to solve by itself, and then sits at its monitor waiting someone to solve the problem for her/him. At least. What have you tried?

Comment: you can do a simple split on '+' to remove string...
then split again on ' ' to give only 00000004000...
then convert it to int or double

Comment: I'm with @captainsac - given the example in the question, SubString will work 100%. Now, if the questioner wanted something more flexible, they should have made that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
string extract = Regex.Replace(myPurseBalance, @"(.*?)\: \+[0]*(?<val>\d+) (.*)", "${val}")
```

It searches for the decimals after `:`, trims the leading `0`s and removes everything after the last whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

if your string format/pattern is fix then you can get specific value

```
  string myPurseBalance = "Purse Balance: +0000004000 556080";
            //
  var newPursebal =Convert.ToDouble(myPurseBalance.Split('+')[1].Split(' ')[0]);
```

Comment: Why double? Just confusing matters

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to get the +0000004000 and then use [`string.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the last four characters by passing the `Length-4` as starting index.

```
string str = myPurseBalance.Split(' ')[2];
str = str.Substring(str.Length-4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn Regex .  [Here is just simple tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match)

```
using System; 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace regex
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Purse Balance: +0000504000 556080";

    // Here we call Regex.Match.
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"\+[0]*(\d+)",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Here we check the Match instance.
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
        string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
        }
    }
}
```